# redirection to file issues with nohup and pipe

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe, nohup

For the following command:

```
ssh -t esolve@hostname 'sudo nohup bash -c "ls > log 2>&1 &"'
```

I always got error information:

```
       nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

why does this happend and how to avoid this error information?

Besides, in the following (I use it to enable output to both screen and file),

```
   stdbuf -o 0 command|& tee logfile
```

what is the `&`  used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens that the command you're running under `nohup` never writes to stdout or stderr, and that you aren't sending any input to it. But `nohup` has no way to know that, so it tells you that any input would be discarded and any output would be written to `nohup.out`.

To avoid this, redirect `nohup`'s stdin, stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

```
ssh -t esolve@hostname 'sudo nohup bash -c "ls > log 2>&1 &" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null'
```

---

As for `|&`, from the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines-1):

> The format for a pipeline is
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [!] command1 [ [| or |&] command2 …]
> ```
>
> The output of each command in the pipeline is connected via a pipe to the input of the next command. That is, each command reads the previous command’s output. This connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command.
>
> If `|&` is used, the standard error of `command1` is connected to `command2`’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`.

This is a bash extension, also present in zsh.

Comment: it seems to me that when there are output or error information from the command, like `ls` in my script, the output and error are not written to nohup.out, why?

Comment: And with your script, there will be no nohup.out generated on the remote host?

Comment: @misteryes You've redirected `ls`'s stdout and stderr to `log`.